# How do I declare a pointer to a pointer to an array?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a pointer to an array of Ts:

```
T (*anArray)[]; // A pointer to an array of Ts.
```

How do I declare a pointer to a pointer to an array of Ts? (ie. a pointer to the above.)

Is it:

```
T (**anArray)[];
```

or

```
T *(*anArray)[];
```

or

```
T (*anArray)*[];
```

or something else entirely?

Thanks,

Alf

Comment: http://cdecl.org/?q=declare+anArray+as+pointer+to+pointer+to+array+5+of+int

Comment: Have you tested any of them ?

Comment: Is there even such a thing as a pointer to an array of unknown bound?

Answer (score 3):

The first one - `T(**anArray)[];`

Comment: you need the parentheses, otherwise it's an array of pointer to pointer, see [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%2A%2AanArray%5B5%5D). a little bit of background and explanation of the "why" would be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

`T *(*anArray)[];` -> `anArray` is pointer to array of T pointers

`T (**anArray)[];` -> `anArray` is pointer to pointer to array of T

Comment: the last form is invalid syntax and not compile

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that the extra pointers outside of the parenthesis are applied to the type contained in the array, while inside the parenthesis they are applied to the type of the variable itself:

```
int (*array)[10];  // pointer to array of 10 int
int *(*array)[10]; // pointer to array of 10 pointer to int
int (**array)[10]; // pointer to pointer to array of 10 int
```

But the best advice is to avoid the problem and use typedefs:

```
typedef int array_t[10];
array_t **variable;      // pointer to pointer to array of 10 integers
```

Answer (score 0):

Open [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) and then copy-paste the following to the textbox:

- `declare a as pointer to pointer to array 10 of int`

On pasting, it tells you what it means in C++. Well it is this:

- `int (**a)[10]`

I'm sure that is what you're looking for? Play around with the link more. You will learn more syntaxes, and how to say that in words.

Answer (score 0):

A good way of figuring out how to make unusual combinations of pointers like this is as follows: start with the variable name, look right without crossing over parentheses, look left, repeat.  Say what you see in the order that you see it.

For a pointer to a pointer to an array we have

```
int (**a)[5]
```

Start with a. We look right, but there's a paren there, so look left. Ok we see `"*"`, so it's a pointer.  Now we look right again... still a paren, so back to the left.  Another `"*"`, so it's a pointer to a pointer.  Look right, paren, look left, paren, so now we can jump out of the parentheses.  Now we see brackets, so we have a pointer to a pointer to an array.  Finally, look all the way to the left and we see `int`.  Pointer to a pointer to an array of `int`s.